# Select lines from text file which have ids listed as part of a column in another file

Tags: r, shell, awk

Hi I want to do this in AWK or R :

if I have the following 3 files as example where i want to grep the whole line of test_bed_file if the 3th column of that file start with a gene that exist in the test_list_of_genes and put the result in the test_results as it is highlighted below.

```
test_list_of_genes:

AGRN
B3GALT6
TP73

test_bed_file (4 columns tab delimited):

chr1    989121  989367  AGRN.chr1.989132.989357
chr1    989816  989941  AGRN.chr1.989827.989931
chr1    990192  990371  AGRN.chr1.990203.990361
chr1    1146926 1147015 TNFRSF4.chr1.1146938.1147005
chr1    1147072 1147222 TNFRSF4.chr1.1147084.1147212
chr1    1147310 1147528 TNFRSF4.chr1.1147322.1147518
chr1    1167647 1168655 B3GALT6.chr1.1167659.1168645
chr1    1266714 1266926 TAS1R3.chr1.1266726.1266916
chr1    1267006 1267328 TAS1R3.chr1.1267018.1267318
chr1    1267392 1268196 TAS1R3.chr1.1267404.1268186
chr1    3645879 3646022 TP73.chr1.3645891.3646012
chr1    3646552 3646722 TP73.chr1.3646564.3646712
chr1    3647479 3647639 TP73.chr1.3647491.3647629
chr1    3648015 3648130 TP73.chr1.3648027.3648120
chr1    3649299 3649650 TP73.chr1.3649311.3649640
chr1    5923313 5923475 NPHP4.chr1.5923324.5923465

test_results:

chr1    989121  989367  AGRN.chr1.989132.989357
chr1    989816  989941  AGRN.chr1.989827.989931
chr1    990192  990371  AGRN.chr1.990203.990361
chr1    1167647 1168655 B3GALT6.chr1.1167659.1168645
chr1    3645879 3646022 TP73.chr1.3645891.3646012
chr1    3646552 3646722 TP73.chr1.3646564.3646712
chr1    3647479 3647639 TP73.chr1.3647491.3647629
chr1    3648015 3648130 TP73.chr1.3648027.3648120
chr1    3649299 3649650 TP73.chr1.3649311.3649640
```

So far this gave me what I want but not sure though if it is the right solution:

grep -Fwf test_list_of_genes test_bed_file > test_result.txt

any help or suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: I've updated my answer with an equivalent but faster approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it in R...

```
test_bed_file[gsub("\\..*", "", test_bed_file[, 3]) %in% test_list_of_genes,]
```

It deletes everything after the first `.` and checks whether these are in `test_list_of_genes`.  It then extracts those rows of `test_bed_file`

Answer (score 0):

#### Your data

```
test_bed_file <- structure(list(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1"), V2 = c(989121L, 989816L, 990192L, 1146926L, 
1147072L, 1147310L, 1167647L, 1266714L, 1267006L, 1267392L, 3645879L, 
3646552L, 3647479L, 3648015L, 3649299L, 5923313L), V3 = c(989367L, 
989941L, 990371L, 1147015L, 1147222L, 1147528L, 1168655L, 1266926L, 
1267328L, 1268196L, 3646022L, 3646722L, 3647639L, 3648130L, 3649650L, 
5923475L), V4 = c("AGRN.chr1.989132.989357", "AGRN.chr1.989827.989931", 
"AGRN.chr1.990203.990361", "TNFRSF4.chr1.1146938.1147005", "TNFRSF4.chr1.1147084.1147212", 
"TNFRSF4.chr1.1147322.1147518", "B3GALT6.chr1.1167659.1168645", 
"TAS1R3.chr1.1266726.1266916", "TAS1R3.chr1.1267018.1267318", 
"TAS1R3.chr1.1267404.1268186", "TP73.chr1.3645891.3646012", "TP73.chr1.3646564.3646712", 
"TP73.chr1.3647491.3647629", "TP73.chr1.3648027.3648120", "TP73.chr1.3649311.3649640", 
"NPHP4.chr1.5923324.5923465")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))

find <- c("AGRN", "B3GALT6", "TP73")
```

#### regex solution

```
test_bed_file[unlist(sapply(find, function(x) grep(paste0("^", x), test_bed_file$V4))),]
```

This will search for `find[x]` at the start of strings in column V4 of test_bed_file

#### Output

```
         V1      V2      V3                           V4
1: chr1  989121  989367      AGRN.chr1.989132.989357
2: chr1  989816  989941      AGRN.chr1.989827.989931
3: chr1  990192  990371      AGRN.chr1.990203.990361
4: chr1 1167647 1168655 B3GALT6.chr1.1167659.1168645
5: chr1 3645879 3646022    TP73.chr1.3645891.3646012
6: chr1 3646552 3646722    TP73.chr1.3646564.3646712
7: chr1 3647479 3647639    TP73.chr1.3647491.3647629
8: chr1 3648015 3648130    TP73.chr1.3648027.3648120
9: chr1 3649299 3649650    TP73.chr1.3649311.3649640
```

Comment: that works but I would like to have a more general solution and not only for thoses 3 genes

Comment: This will work for any number of genes...simply replace `find` with `test_list_of_genes` to see

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, you're asking:

```
is AGRN.chr1.989132.989357 in array a??
```

You need to extract the gen from that string, like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]; next} {match($NF, /([[:alnum:]]+)\./, arr); if (arr[1] in a) print $0 > "test_results"}' test_list_of_genes test_bed_file
```

No need of external redirection since awk allows it in the code (print $0 > "test_results").

For more info about Awk redirection: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html

The match function extracts the gen into an array (arr). Then you test the gen (arr[1]) against your array of genes (a).

For more info about Awk string functions: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that as well but it gave me error: "syntax error at or near ,"    


Any idea?

Comment: @Alexis_543 it works on my console. May be you lost a double quote in the copy/paste or something.

Answer (score 0):

try in awk solution too as follows.

```
 awk  'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next} ($7 in a) || ($9 in a)'   test_list_of_genes  FS='[ .]' test_be_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding output as per OP's request.

```
awk  'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next} ($7 in a) || ($9 in a)'   test_list_of_genes  FS='[ .]' test_be_file
chr1    989121  989367  AGRN.chr1.989132.989357
chr1    989816  989941  AGRN.chr1.989827.989931
chr1    990192  990371  AGRN.chr1.990203.990361
chr1    1167647 1168655 B3GALT6.chr1.1167659.1168645
chr1    3645879 3646022 TP73.chr1.3645891.3646012
chr1    3646552 3646722 TP73.chr1.3646564.3646712
chr1    3647479 3647639 TP73.chr1.3647491.3647629
chr1    3648015 3648130 TP73.chr1.3648027.3648120
chr1    3649299 3649650 TP73.chr1.3649311.3649640
```

Comment: I tried that but it gave me all the lines in test_bed_file as a results. Any idea why this didn't work?

Comment: It worked for me, I hope you are using same code and same kind of Input_files which you given like sample.

Comment: What is the $7 and $9 referred to?

Comment: Please check my EDIT now where I am getting output properly, also check if your files have carriage characters or not by doing cat -v Input_file, let me know on same if you find any carriage characters.

Comment: I still get the same results as before and by the way I cannot see any update in the new command. Also to mention that the test_bed_file is a tab delimited

Comment: try changing FS='[\t.]' and let me know how it goes because when I copied data from your post they didn't come tab delimited apologies for it.

Comment: I tried this but Unfortunately again I got all the lines in test_bed_file :(

 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next} ($7 in a) || ($9 in a)' test_list_of_genes  FS='[\t.]' test_bed_file